# C finding newline chartacters in my buffer from a read system call

Tags: c, linux, file-io

**This is Homework!**

currently im working on an assignment where i need to read in characters from a file using read call then write the characters out to the screen one at a time.... ok no problem there, but after each line i need increment a line counter by one, and every 20 lines i need to pause the output until the user presses a space

```
        char buffer[1];
        int n_char = 0;
        //read (fileDesc, buffer, 5);

        while( (n_char=read(fileDesc, buffer, 1))!=0) 
        {   
            if (buffer[1] == '\n')
            {
                //this is not incementing?
                lineCount++;

            }

            if (lineCount % 20 == 0)
            {
                //wait for a space to be pressed
                //for the time being sleep to make sure im counting lines correctly
                sleep(5);
            }

            n_char=write(1,buffer,n_char); 
        }
```

for the moment im having an issue figuring out why i cant detect newline characters, any help woudl be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `buffer` is declared

```
char buffer[1];
```

which means one character, *but* to access the first character, you must say

```
if (buffer[0] == '\n')
```

Array indexes start at `0`.

Comment: Why use a one-element array? You might as well omit the array part, and simply use `char buffer` and `read(fileDesc, &buffer, 1)`.